# How Does My Recursion Solution for Getting The Values Within A Range Truly work?

Tags: javascript

I been working on this problem that asks to find the values within the two given inputs. For instance, input: (1,5) yields the result: [1,2,3,4,5]. This problem should give a solution that is done recursively.

Here is the solution that works:

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum - startNum === 0) {
    return [startNum];
  } else {
    var numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1);
    numbers.push(endNum);
    console.log(numbers); 
    return numbers;
  }
}
```

The trouble that I am having is understanding how this solution works. I tried debugging through console.log and it looks like values are added like this:

```
[ 1, 2 ]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

If my endNum value is declared as 5 initially and I'm pushing endNum to the end of the array, why doesn't my array look like this: 
[ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]

What's surprising was when I changed my recursive function to this:

```
var numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum+1, endNum);
numbers.push(startNum);
```

The array looked like this:

```
[ 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
```

Any feedback or clarification on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: With the first example, your base case (innermost call to `rangeOfNumbers()`) is `startNum = 1, endNum = 1`. After your modification, the base case becomes `startNum = 5, endNum = 5`.

Comment: You don't push `endNum` into the array until **after** you have constructed the array with all the lower values of `endNum` in it first. So you end up pushing `1` (when `endNum - startNum === 0`), then `2`, then `3`, then `4` and finally `5`.

Comment: `numbers` always starts as `[startNum]` and the call just before the one that returns `[startNum]` is the call that has `endNum` set to `2`, in the one before that it is `3` and so on.

Comment: @Nick I partially understand your comment. If nothing is pushed until I have constructed the array with all the lower values of `endNum` in it first. How do the statements execute?

Is it something like this:

`1. rangeOfNumbers(1, 5 - 1)`
`2. rangeOfNumbers(1, 4 - 1)`
`3. rangeOfNumbers(1, 3 - 1)`
`4. rangeOfNumbers(1, 2 - 1)`
`5. rangeOfNumbers(1, 1 - 1)`

And then my values are pushed starting from statement 5?

Comment: @traveler316 yes - but there will be no `5.` as the `rangeOfNumbers(1, 2 - 1)` call will not recurse since it will meet the `endNum - startNum === 0` condition and thus start the unrolling of the recursion.

Comment: @Nick Just to sum it up, the sequence of events would be statements 1-4 would execute (in that order) then we would add the results from statements 4-1 to the numbers array. Is that correct?

Comment: @traveler316 yes, that's it. As the recursion unrolls, those results get added, so it's in the *reverse* order to the calls, which is why the final array comes out as `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: @Nick. Perfect, thank you for explaining this to me!

Comment: @traveler316 no worries. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

basically what it does is the following:

1) check that number(`endNum`) is equals to `startNum`. (this is the breaker condition)
2) if they are not equals, it will call the function `rangeOfNumbers` with an `endNum` reduced by 1.

### now lets take an example of `rangeOfNumbers(1,3)` so it is smaller.

lets call each return `number#X` so we now what we are assigning

1) `rangeOfNumbers(1,3).`

`start` is not equal to `end` *(1!==3)*, therefore we call again `rangeOfNumbers` and assign it to the variable `numbers`**(number#1)** and the end is reduced by one.

2)`rangeOfNumbers(1,2).`

`start` is not equal to `end`*(1!==3)*, therefore we call again `rangeOfNumbers` and assign it to the variable `numbers`**(number#2)** and the end is reduced by one.

3)
rangeOfNumbers(1,1).

start is equal to end(1 === 1), therefore we return `[1]` (startNum)

4) 
basically we assign this value to `number#2` and then we push `endNum` (from step 2 ;)), so we do:

```
// equal to do [1].push(2) because endNum in step2 was 2.
numbers.push(endNum);
return numbers;
```

5) 
on this step we assign to `number#1`  the returned value from step 4, which is [1, 2] and we do the same that on step 4;

```
// equal to do [1, 2].push(3) because endNum in step1 was 3.
numbers.push(endNum);
return numbers;
```

6) 
we return that last return, so end of the function.

`[1, 2, 3]`

in other form to see it, it could be something like

```
rangeOfNumbers(1,1) --> this returns [1]
rangeOfNumbers(1,2) --> this returns [1, 2]
rangeOfNumbers(1,3) --> this returns [1, 2, 3]
console.log(result)
```

this is read from the bottom to the top, like a `LIFO`

read [this article](https://www.thecodingdelight.com/understanding-recursion-javascript/), explains everything in detail with images

answering your question on why:
`var numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum+1, endNum);`
makes your array to be `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]` it is because you are rising your `start` from 1 to 5, and then you start pushing. if you read my previous answer, it will be clear for you to discover why.

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  if (endNum - startNum === 0) {
    return [startNum];
  } else {
    let numbers = rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1);
    numbers.push(endNum)
    return numbers;
  }
}


console.log(rangeOfNumbers(1, 5));
```

Comment: In steps 1-3, is it `end` that is assigned to numbers? or is it `start` that is assigned to the return statement: `number#X`?

Comment: sorry @traveler316 you are correct, it is `start` but remember that it doesn't matter, because `startNum === endNumb`